# How to call web api in Angular and it will with user IP address

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 10.
I am trying to find a way to call an external API using POST WEB API method.
While I need the external API to be able to recognize the call is from the user's IP address.
Any method that able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `HttpClient` of [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/http) or you can use built-in `fetch` method from [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

**HttpClient** Example:

```
// import HttpClientModule inside your app.module

// inside your service or component.
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

callApi() {
    return this.http.post("http://myhostlink/api/path");
}
```

Fetch Example (from docs):

```
// Example POST method implementation:
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}
```

Comment: Actually I do try this but it will have Cross-Origin issue.
I am trying to access API which is at another host.

Comment: This issue must handled from the server side, not from client